# Why is my Linux reporting an allowable size error when building an .ISO?

Tags: linux, iso-image

I have played with Linux customization, when I want to build the .ISO I get this error:

```
$ mkisofs -r -o rhel.iso -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat ./
INFO: UTF-8 character encoding detected by locale settings.
Assuming UTF-8 encoded filenames on source filesystem,
use -input-charset to override.
Unknown file type (unallocated) ./.. - ignoring and continuing.
Using RELEA000.HTM;1 for /RELEASE-NOTES-pt_BR.html (RELEASE-NOTES-U1-pt_BR.html)

Size of boot image is 20 sectors -> mkisofs: Error - boot image './isolinux/isolinux.bin' has not an allowable size.
```

I didnt change the `isolinux.bin`... Why do I receive the above error message?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should add these parameters to the command:

```
-no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table
```

The parameters are:

- **`no-emul-boot`**: Specifies that the boot image used to create "El Torito" bootable CDs is a 'no emulation' image. The system will load and execute this image without performing any disk emulation
- **`boot-load-size`**: Specifies the number of "virtual" (512-byte) sectors to load in no-emulation mode. The default is to load the entire boot file. Some BIOSes may have problems if this is not a multiple of 4.
- **`boot-info-table`**: Specifies that a 56-byte table with information of the CD-ROM layout will be patched in at offset 8 in the boot file. If this option is given, the boot file is modified in the source filesystem, so make sure to make a copy if this file cannot be easily regenerated! See the EL TORITO BOOT INFO TABLE section for a description of this table.

For more information, see [`man mkisofs`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mkisofs).

Comment: What does that do?

Comment: **no-emul-boot** Specifies that the boot image used to create "El Torito" bootable CDs is a 'no emulation' image. The system will load and execute this image without performing any disk emulation

Comment: **boot-load-size** Specifies the number of "virtual" (512-byte) sectors to load in no-emulation mode. The default is to load the entire boot file. Some BIOSes may have problems if this is not a multiple of 4.

Comment: **boot-info-table** Specifies that a 56-byte table with information of the CD-ROM layout will be patched in at offset 8 in the boot file. If this option is given, the boot file is modified in the source filesystem, so make sure to make a copy if this file cannot be easily regenerated! See the EL TORITO BOOT INFO TABLE section for a description of this table.

Comment: Thanks for providing that information. Welcome to Super User! +1

Comment: "Some BIOSes may have problems if this is not a multiple of 4. ". On my system e.g. 8 did not work out `isohybrid: new1.iso: unexpected boot catalogue parameters`, why other multiples like 8 does not work?